# Ask about Linkedin `realtimeFrontendClientConnectivityTracking` API

Tags: authentication, cookies, linkedin-api

I'm investigating how to log in to my Linkedin account on another browser using cookies. I could log in but during the process, suddenly my account has been logged out. I checked and found that a Linkedin API was called and my cookie expired and was deleted after this API was failed (https://www.linkedin.com/realtime/realtimeFrontendClientConnectivityTracking?action=sendHeartbeat), it returned 401 error code and delete cookies request.
I also realized that this API was called many times but the previous APIs were called normally until suddenly an error occurred.

`401 error`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXxMm.png)

`Cookies were deleted`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAy2j.png)

`Previous APIs was run properly`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JmtR.png)

Do you guys know how to bypass the API and keep my account logged in?